# Auto Scroll Down a shell usin jsch

Tags: java, jsch

I am facing a problem in Java jsch. I have opened a Shell channel and I have a list of commands that I want to execute and read from the shell.

But in that commands list, there's one command that needs to be scrolled down in the shell to be shown until its end.

I am strugling to implement this auto-scroller for that command.

In my code What I did:

```
    ChannelShell channelShell = (ChannelShell) session.openChannel("shell");
    OutputStream inputstream_for_the_channel = channelShell.getOutputStream();
    InputStream outputstream_from_the_channel = channelShell.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outputstream_from_the_channel));
    PrintStream commander = new PrintStream(inputstream_for_the_channel, true);

    channelShell.connect();

    if (!commands.get(0).equals("show system information | match \"System Name\"")) {
        commands.add(0, "show system information | match \"System Name\"");
    }

    String readString = "";
    String line;
    int index = 0;

    for (String cmd : commands) {
        System.out.println(cmd);

        commander.println(cmd);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(commandsSleep);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
        }

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (cmd.equals("admin display-config")) {
                commander.println("");
            }

            GuiApp.textAreaLog.append("\n"+ ++index + " : " + line);
            System.out.println(index + " : " + line);
            readString += (line+"\n");
        }

    }


    if (routerType.equals("nokia")) {
        commander.println("logout");
        System.out.println("logout");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(commandsSleep);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
        }
    } else if (routerType.equals("linux")){
        commander.println("exit");
    }

    commander.close();
    channelShell.disconnect();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(commandsSleep);
    } catch (Exception ee) {
    }


    return readString;
```

In the part:

```
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (cmd.equals("admin display-config")) {
            commander.println("");
        }

        GuiApp.textAreaLog.append("\n"+ ++index + " : " + line);
        System.out.println(index + " : " + line);
        readString += (line+"\n");
    }
```

Is where I tried to implement a While loop to read the reader until its null, and to add to the commander a printl with "" to try to scroll this problematic command further down.

Comment: Ok, this program is for routers. And actually, I find out that to solve this, with others routers commands the "environment no more" command is needed before. But I'll leave the question here, to see if there's a way to do it the input_streamer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I managed to do was to insert a timelimiter to the readbuffer.

```
for (String cmd : commands) {
    GuiApp.textAreaLog.append("\n"+"Running Command : " + cmd);
    commander.println(cmd);
    System.out.println(cmd);
    if (cmd.equals("admin display-config")) {
        commandDelay = commandsSleep*10;
    }else{
        commandDelay = commandsSleep;
    }
    line = reader.readLine();
    while (line!=null)
    {

        System.out.println(++index + " : " + line);
        readString += (line+"\n");
        try {
            line = timeLimiter.callWithTimeout(reader::readLine, commandsSleep, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(commandDelay);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GuiApp.textAreaLog.append("\n"+"Comando executado com sucesso");
}
```